# Post Request stuck on Postman

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express

I am learning to build API using Node.js, Express and MongoDB. I am on early learning phase.
My code are as follow.

```
const app = express();

const mongojs = require("mongojs");

const { body, param, validationResult } = require("express-validator");

const db = mongojs("travel", ["records"]);

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.get("/api/records", function (req, res) {
  const options = req.query;

  const sort = options.sort || {};
  const filter = options.filter || {};
  const limit = 2;
  const page = parseInt(options.page) || 1;
  const skip = (page - 1) * limit;

  for (var i in sort) {
    sort[i] = parseInt(sort[i]);
  }

  db.records
    .find(filter)
    .sort(sort)
    .skip(skip)
    .limit(limit, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        return res.sendStatus(500);
      } else {
        return res.status(200).json({
          meta: {
            filter,
            sort,
            skip,
            limit,
            page,
            total: data.length,
          },
          data,
          links: {
            self: req.originalUrl,
          },
        });
      }
    });
});

app.post("/api/records", function (req, res) {
  db.records.insert(req.body, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500);
    }

    const _id = data._id;
    res.append("Location", "/api/records/" + _id);
    return res.send(201).json({
      meta: { _id },
      data,
    });
  });
});


app.listen(8000, function () {
  console.log("Server running at port 8000...");
});
```

When I try GET request on Postman, it works fine. But when I try POST request, it shows like the following. [error msg image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/180Fu.png).
Please let me know what is wrong here.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Add `err` content to your post

Comment: My `POST` method worked fine after adding query validation. I was trying to post without providing data any data. Now it response error arrays after validation fail. Thanks for the help though.